# How to rewrite script with partition by

Tags: sql

I have table with two groups of columns. First group I use to get row_num `(row_num() partition by ...)` and second to get number of duplicates `(count() partition by ...)` and I want to select all rows where row_num is 1 united with row where duplicates > 1.

```
create table source
(
    id      int primary key,
    name    varchar(10),
    surname varchar(10),
    day_number     int,
    height int
);


insert into source(
    id,
    name,
    surname,
    day_number,
    height
)
values
       (1,'Mike', 'Wilson', 1, 160),
       (2,'Mike', 'Wilson', 1, 165),

       (3,'Mike', 'Wilson', 2, 170),

       (4,'Mike', 'Wilson', 3, 175),
       (5,'Mike', 'Wilson', 3, 180),
       
       (6,'John', 'Conor', 1, 160),
       (7,'John', 'Conor', 1, 165),

       (8,'John', 'Conor', 2, 170),

       (9,'John', 'Conor', 3, 175);
```

The expected result is

```
(1,'Mike', 'Wilson', 1, 160),
(2,'Mike', 'Wilson', 1, 165),
(4,'Mike', 'Wilson', 3, 175),
(5,'Mike', 'Wilson', 3, 180),
(6,'John', 'Conor', 1, 160),
(7,'John', 'Conor', 1, 165),
(9,'John', 'Conor', 3, 175)
```

Could you help me improve the select? with analytic function?

```
with t1 as (
    select row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by id, height) as row_num as row_num,
           count(*) over (partition by name, surname, day_number)             as amount,
           *
    from source
),
     t2 as (
         select *
         from t1
         where row_num = 1
     )
select *
from t2
union
select t1.*
from t1
         join t2 on t1.name = t2.name
    and t1.surname = t2.surname
where t1.amount > 1;
```

Comment: Your expected result doesn't make much sense to me.  What makes a row a "duplicate"?

Comment: How does row with id 3 and 8 magically disappear???

Comment: @Dave Costa Row makes "duplicate" a second group of three fields - name, surname, day_number

Comment: @Vadim, do you try query?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only CTE t1:

```
select Y.id, Y.Name,Y.surname,Y.day_number,Y.height from  t1 X left join t1 Y
on X.name = Y.name
and X.surname = Y.surname
where X.row_num=1 AND Y.amount > 1 
order by Y.id
```

Due to the fact that window function's value calculated for each row (`amount` for all rows will be *the *same** `within partition by name, surname, day_number`)  and therefore row_num=1 also will enclude in it,then you can try more simple query:

```
select id,name,surname,day_number from 
(
 select count(*) over (partition by name, surname, day_number) as amount,
  * from  source
)X
 where amount>1
order by id
```

And in your desired output there's row:

```
(9,'John', 'Conor', 3, 175)
```

but this record (John Conor)doesn't have duplicate with day_number=3